# nginx rate limiting with exception for some paths

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting, except

I need to rate limit IPs for all locations, except the following : */api/v1/ex/au/* and */api/v2/ex/au/*

I am using the following config in /etc/nginx/conf.d/mywebsite.conf:

```
geo $whitelist {
      default 0;
      include /etc/nginx/whitelisted_ips.txt;
}
    
map $whitelist $limitmap {
      0 $binary_remote_addr;
      1 "";
}
    
limit_req_zone $limitmap zone=myratelimit:50m  rate=10r/s;

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ...
    location ~ /api/v1/ex/au/ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~ /api/v2/ex/au/ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location / {
            limit_req zone=myratelimit burst=10 nodelay;
            limit_req_status     429;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            limit_req zone=myratelimit burst=10 nodelay;
            limit_req_status 429;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
            ...
    }
```

}

Testing with siege, I still get 429 when request for /api/v1/ex/au/ and /api/v2/ex/au/.
Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Shouldn't `binary_remote_addr` have a `$` in front of it?

Comment: nice catch. yes. I've just edited. wasn't the issue for the rate limiting though, but thanks anyway

Comment: remove the `~` from the location. It is not needed in this case. Try again.

Comment: removed the "~" from /api/v1/ex/au/ location. still getting rate limited when requesting /api/v1/ex/au/ :(

Comment: Why do you need `try_files` in API locations?

Comment: what is your nginx version